# Manga about modern-day high school student who meets a girl with a sword who wears bunny ears and claims to be his fiancée

Tags: story-identification, magic, manga

I read this manga a few years ago.

It's set in the modern day and it's about a high school student who meets a girl with a sword who wears bunny ears and claims to be his fiancée. She says that he is a prince of a country of magic and he is a candidate for the throne and that she is here to protect him from his siblings, and is then attacked by a girl who can control plants and she is cursed to not be able to sleep. Then, he unlocks the power of the royal family that can nullify all magic through this metal golem ghost thing that floats behind him like a stand from JoJo. The golem could turn into this shoggoth like thing duing either chapter 8 or 9 I think.

Also, it turns out some of the characters are based off of fairy tale characters like the thorn girl is sleeping beauty and the next antagonist I remember was Snow White who has magic that can control up to 7 things using her "dwarves".

As for coloring, it was color for the first few pages like some manga but black and white for the rest. The girl wore a kimono and had a katana.

I believe the title has to do with the word "rabbit" or "bunny" so I tried "kaguya inaba usagi" and such things like that.

Comment: Was this manga in full colour or mostly black & white?

Comment: This all sounds perfectly mundane

Comment: It was black white with a few color pages in front like some manga. As for it being mundane it really wasnt it was kind of cool like the golem could turn into this shoggoth like thing duing either chap 8 or 9 I think

Comment: There's a "based on a fairytale" tag on mangaupdates that is worth a look. None of the descriptions I saw looked like a good match, but you might be able to recognize a cover image.

Comment: Couldnt find it there or may have skipped it

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/how-to-ask-a-good-anime-manga-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Answer (score 0):

Could this be [*Maken-Ki!*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maken-ki!) (*AKA. Competitive Spirit!*)?

> Ooyama Takeru, a young normal yet perverted minded guy, got accepted
> and now goes to a school that, unknown to him, was where combat and
> magic is used. On the first day, he meets again after three years:
> Amaya Haruko, his childhood friend, Kushiya Inaho, a girl who says
> she's his fiance, and Himegami Kodama, a blonde who wants to kill him.
>
> [image]

Comment: For the record, this manga is ***dreadful*** and the fights (and most of the rest of the plot) are basically an excuse for the female characters to show their pants.

Comment: Notably, the New Zealand authorities refused the anime adaptation a classification due to its 'significant objectionable content' and refused to accept the makers excuse that the characters, while young-looking and dressed in traditional high school outfits, are supposedly upper students at a prep school.

Comment: In order no it's not maken ki it's something else. As for coloring it was like color for the first few pages like some manga do but black white for the rest the girl wore a kimono and had a katana